# How to unlock Eve's Dead Bird?

Tags: achievements, the-binding-of-isaac

The achievement description says:

```
Make 2 deals with the devil in one play through.
```

My only question is, does it count if I make two deals with the same appearance of the devil? When you meet the devil he always has two offers, if I take both, do they both count? Or does the achievement only count separate meetings with the devil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, confirmed - you can unlock Eve by making two deals with the same devil (i.e. purchasing both deals in the one room). By side effect, you also unlock her Dead Bird and Whore of Babylon ("The Curse"), which is announced upon leaving the room.

*Source*: Me, having just now done exactly that and unlocking her.

Comment: I had tried it and it hadn't worked. But I guess they changed it in this update that happened just 30 min ago. =)

Comment: I made two deals with the devil today and didn't get the achievement/unlock. I read on the wiki somewhere you need to make three deals in one play. Any truth to this?

Comment: @Dycker Every official source including the game itself (in character select) says two deals.

Comment: @Dycker There was a bug, which required you to make three deals with him. This should be fixed in the latest patch.

Comment: I tested after update, and @JonathanHobbs is right.

Comment: Before the Halloween update, Edmund McMillen (the developer)'s twitter comments initially said it was 3, either it was a mistake or it was changed later on, but it caused alot of confusion. Especially since some people still encountered bugs in unlocking her. Er... him?

Answer (score 2):

If the patch notes are to be believed, then you have to make a total of 2 deals with the devil in two separate encounters.

Source: http://store.steampowered.com/news/6676/